# Blackjack program CPU keeps dealing.(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I recently started python (3.7) in school and my most recent assignment is to create a simple blackjack game. I've almost finished, but there is one problem, after the user Twists or Sticks it goes straight to the Cpu and they just keep dealing cards. My twist function works fine and the program lets you choose whether an ace is a one or eleven after you choose to stick, but after it displays the user takes their turn, the programs keeps repeating "The dealer's second card is..." "The dealer's total is..." befor stopping randomly with the line "The dealer has stuck with..." I'm sure there is some easy fix that someone can help me with and the problem is probably due to some basic misunderstanding of how while loops work, so any help is appreciated. Sorry for any messy code, this is one of my first programs.

Thanks in advance, code is below

```
#Allows user to Twist or Stick     
while userStick == False:
    userChoice = input("Twist (T) or Stick (S)?")
    if userChoice == ("T"):
        userNumThree = random.randint(1,13)
        if userNumThree == 11 or userNumThree ==12 or userNumThree == 13:
            userNumThree = 10
        userTotal = userTotal + userNumThree
        print ("Your next card is...")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print (userNumThree)
        if userNumThree == 1 and userAce == False:
            userAce = True
            time.sleep(0.5)
        print ("Your total is...")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print (userTotal)
        if userTotal > 21:
            userBust = True
            print ("You have bust!")
            break

    if userChoice == ("S"):
        userStick = True
        if userAce == True:
            aceNumber = input("Do you want your ace to be a 1 or and 11")
            if aceNumber == "11":
                userTotal = userTotal + 10
            elif aceNumber == "1":
                userTotal == userTotal
            else:
                print ("I did not understand that number, so one has been chosen as default")
        print ("Okay, your final total is...")
        print (userTotal)
    break


#Allows the dealer to twist or stick            
while cpuStick == False:
    cpuTotal = cpuNumTwo
    if cpuTotal < 17:
        cpuNumThree = random.randint(1,13)
        if cpuNumThree == 11 or cpuNumThree == 12 or userNumThree == 13:
            cpuNumThree = 10
        if cpuNumThree == 1 and cpuAce == False:
            cpuAce = True
        cpuTotal = cpuTotal + cpuNumThree
        if cpuAce == True and cpuTotal + 10  >= 17 and cpuTotal + 10 <= 21:
            cpuStick = True
            cpuTotal = cpuTotal + 10
            print ("The Cpu has stuck with...")
            print (cpuTotal)                
            break

        print ("The dealer's second card is...")
        print (cpuNumThree)
        print ("The dealer's total is...")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print (cpuTotal)

    elif cpuTotal >= 17:
        cpuStick = True
        print("The cpu has stuck with...")
        print (cpuTotal)
        break


    if cpuTotal > 21:
        cpuBust = True
        print("The dealer has Bust! You win")
        break

if userStick == True and cpuStick == True:
    if userStick > cpuStick:
        print ("You win!")
    elif cpuStick > userStick:
        print ("You lose!")
```

Comment: Notice that the first while loop `break`s at the end (explicitly exits the while loop), and that in the while loop below `#Allows the dealer to twist or stick` (which is where the dealer plays), there is no code for user input.

Comment: Possibly you want that first `break` to be part of the `if` block just above it?

Comment: You are also resetting `cpuTotal` to the value of `cpuNumTwo` (which is not being touched in the CPU loop at all), which causes the indefinite looping for the CPU.

Comment: @Jerry so what do I do, swapping the variable order caused an error?

Comment: unrelated `if userNumThree == 11 or userNumThree ==12 or userNumThree == 13:` == `if userNumThree in {11,12,13}:`

Comment: @ElSponge it really is up to you as to what you can do. You need to find the logic behind what should happen and code accordingly. Personally, I can't say I understand what you are trying to do. I would say the variable names `NumThree` and `NumTwo` confuse me as to what they represent. Incidentally I just completed my own simple BlackJack game simulator assignment a couple of hours ago, but I can't say it looks close to your code :(

Comment: @Scott and Jerry I used both of your ideas and it worked, now I just need to fix the winner display!

Comment: @Patrick Thanks, will edit my code to make it more efficient

Comment: Is it possible to choose two answers as it was a mix of Jerry's and Scott

Comment: @ElSponge your upvotes are yours to distribute as you see fit.